# Handling Task Exceptions - custom TaskScheduler

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am writing a custom FIFO-queued thread-limited task scheduler.

1. I would like to be able to guarantee that **unhandled** task exceptions bubble up or escalate immediately, and proceed to end the process.
2. I would also like to be able to `Task.Wait()` and **handle** an `AggregateException` that might pop out, without causing the process to end.

Can these two requirements be met simultaneously? Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

---

**Further information**

The crux of the issue is that I don't always want to `Task.Wait()` on a task to complete.

After executing the task on my custom task scheduler, I know that unhandled task exceptions will eventually [escalate when the Task is cleaned up by the GC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> If you do not wait on a task that propagates an exception, or access its Exception property, the exception is escalated according to the .NET exception policy when the task is garbage-collected.

But who knows when that will happen in the environment in which the application executes - this can't be determined at design time.

To me, this means that unhandled exceptions in tasks can potentially go undetected **- forever.** That leaves a bad taste in my mouth.

If I want to ensure that unhandled task exceptions are escalated immediately, I can do the following in my task scheduler after the task is executed:

```
while ( taskOnQueue )
{
    /// dequeue a task

    TryExecuteTask(task);

    if (task.IsFaulted) 
    { 
        throw task.Exception.Flatten(); 
    }
}
```

But by doing this I basically guarantee that the exception will always terminate the process, regardless of how it may be handled by catching an `AggregateException` at `Task.Wait()` (or in a `TaskScheduler.UnobservedException` event handler).

Given these options - do I really have to choose one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given these options - do I really have to choose one or the other?

Yes, you pretty much do. The only way to know for sure that a `Task` will not be `Wait`ed on is to find out that the `Task` is inaccessible from the executing program, which is what the GC does. Even if you could figure out whether some thread is currently `Wait`ing on the `Task`, that's not enough: the `Task` might be stored in some data structure somewhere and it will be `Wait`ed on at some point in the future.

The only alternative I can think of, and it's a really terrible option, especially from performance perspective, is to call `GC.Collect()` after every `Task` completes. That way, every `Task` that is unreachable at the point in time when it completes will be immediately considered unhandled. But even this isn't reliable, because a `Task` might become unreachable after it's completed.

Comment: Yes I agree - I'm not at all interested in interfering with the normal operation of the GC.

Answer (score 2):

> To me, this means that unhandled exceptions in tasks can potentially go undetected - forever. That leaves a bad taste in my mouth.

This is true and you have no way of changing that. Point (1) is a lost cause.

I do not understand the point of the following:

```
if (task.IsFaulted) 
{ 
    throw task.Exception.Flatten(); 
}
```

This means that *any* task exception, even a handled one, will throw this exception This limits the tasks that you can reasonably create on this scheduler.

(Also I don't see why you flatten; even `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is better. Probably, you should wrap instead of fake-rethrowing.)

Also see svicks answer.

Can't you just hook the unhandled exception event and report such cases to the developers? Unhandled task exceptions are sometimes bugs, but in my experience rarely fatal.

If you really don't need tasks to throw exceptions, you can schedule tasks using a helper method that wraps the task body with:

```
try {
 body();
} catch (...) { ... }
```

That would be a rather clean way to do it, flexible and does not depend on a custom scheduler.

Comment: Thanks. The custom scheduler isn't for the purpose of handling task exceptions, it's required for more deterministic task execution than the default scheduler provides.  The point of the `if (task.IsFaulted) ...` code is to *immediately* cause the exception to escalate, rather than waiting for the GC in the case where the task is not `Task.Wait()` waited upon.  But the caveat you note is correct and exactly why I'm stuck between these options.

Comment: I actually think that wrapping the task in a `try-catch` will be an acceptable solution, either within the task code itself or by using a helper method or a precedent task which is only used to await completion of the first.

Comment: Right, I meant to suggest a continuation task that observes and logs the exception but for some reason it slipped off my mind while writing the answer.

Comment: Yes I think that's another good approach. I can observe and log the exception there, or if I want to meet the immediate escalation policy depending on the nature of the exception I can rethrow the exception directly onto the threadpool.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer so I can describe details which are important to the options as discussed in comments with **usr**.

There are (at least) two task-based approaches when using a separate method for logging or handling of task exceptions:

1. A continuation task using `task.ContinueWith()`
2. A second task which is created and scheduled immediately following the first

The distinction is important in my case because the custom scheduler is responsible for guaranteed FIFO scheduling of tasks which are presented to it across a guaranteed number of threads.

**NB: due to the operation of the custom scheduler, the second task is guaranteed to run on the same thread as the first after the first task completes.**

Option 1 - a continuation task

```
Task task = new Task(() => DoStuff());
task.ContinueWith(t => HandleTaskExceptions(t), customScheduler);
task.Start(customScheduler);
```

Option 2 - a second task scheduled immediately after the first

```
Task task = new Task(() => DoStuff());
task.Start(customScheduler);

Task task2 = new Task(() => HandleTaskExceptions(task));
task2.Start(customScheduler);
```

The distinction is in when the second task is **scheduled** to run.

Using option 1 with a [task continuation means that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dd321307%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The returned Task will not be scheduled for execution until the current task has completed, whether it completes due to running to completion successfully, faulting due to an unhandled exception, or exiting out early due to being canceled.

This means that the continuation may be placed at the end of a task queue, which further means that exceptions may not be handled or logged until after additional work has been done.  This may impact upon the overall application state.

Using option 2, the exceptions are guaranteed to be handled immediately following completion of the first task, as the handler-task is the next in the queue.

`HandleTaskExceptions()` can be as simple as:

```
void HandleTaskExceptions(Task task)
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        /// handle task exceptions
    }
}
```